# Steam auth login api

Tags: php, steam, steam-web-api

When I login on one page with the steam auth login I can use all the infomation from the $steamprofile array, but when I change to another php file I dont have accses to the same $steamprofile array, how do I get this to work? I have tried to setup session_start(); on both files but diden't work.

Comment: can you paste your steam auth code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you login using the SteamAPI you get a response with all the data which can be viewed on one page, if you want it to be saved in a session you need to save this data in $_SESSION array in PHP.

For example:

```
$_SESSION['steamid'] = $steamprofile['steamid'];
echo $_SESSION['steamid']; // on a different page
```

You then need to include session_start() on all pages you want to share those information with. Read more about PHP session [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp).

Comment: so i have to put it all in $_session?
so like:
$_session['steamid'] = $response['steamid'];
$_session['tradeurl'] = $_session['tradeurl'];
ect..

Comment: yes, and then you can use $_SESSION['steamid'] variable on other pages as it's shared in a session cookie

Comment: So, session_start(); first file,
$_SESSION['steamid'] = $steamprofile['steamid'];
second file, session_start(); again
but when i use the $_session['steamid'] in the other file it just gives me an error